# SSIS set records that contains characters as null values

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, etl

I'm new using SSIS, i'm using a derived column to find and remove characters("DI") from numbers, but with this one I've notice that some records have some extra characters after "DI", i need the ones that only have "DI", how can i set the records that contains those extra characters as null values(without messing the ones containing only "DI")?

Comment: I think that you should add a script component to achieve that using Regular Expression

Answer (score 0):

SSIS has a few ways you could do this, but a couple simple ones would be to use SQL. Something like this.  I used TRY_CAST to INT, but you could change the data type if needed.  The first one also depends more on the SQL Server version.  It was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT
    TRY_CAST(REPLACE(t.ColumnName,'DI','') AS INT) AS ColumnName
FROM SchemaName.TableName AS t
```

or another option if you use an older SQL...

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(t.ColumnName,'DI','')) = 1
        THEN REPLACE(t.ColumnName,'DI','')
        ELSE NULL
    END AS ColumnName
FROM SchemaName.TableName AS t
```

On your SOURCE to DESTINATION, you'd change the SOURCE to use a SQL script instead of a direct table/view.

Comment: Got it and makes sense, (btw I'm using SQL Server 2014) but i need to execute that "filter" in between processes, and the way you said ain't helping with that

Comment: Describe the SSIS tasks you have so far... is it a basic SOURCE to DESTINATION where you want to put a filter between the 2?  Is there more to it?  I'm wondering if you could put:

TRY_CAST(REPLACE(t.ColumnName,'DI','') AS INT) IS NOT NULL

in the where.

Comment: Ok, as i said I'm new with this, should process this data (+6K) records, change the date format(done with a DerivedC), select the IDs, but this IDs come with national(9 digits), outsiders(DI+12 digits) and data consider as garbage, already remove that garbage IDs(DerivedC again), should select those beginning with DI remove the "DI" and left the ones with a length of 12 or more, but some of those DI bring others characters, i was using an script component to remove all the characters, but the outsiders ID length once removed the characters

Comment: contain 9 digit as if were national which is wrong, so setting the remaining null may help thou

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i figured out the way to make it work, splitting by the lengths to filter and then mixing, so thank you for the help!